# Wrong link from the ignored tag message on the end of the questions list

Tags: bug, hyperlinks, ignored-tags

If you have any ignored tag you will see the link “Ignored Tags preferences” in the end of questions list, e.g. on [the week tab](https://meta.stackexchange.com/?tab=week):

> [image: tag preferences]

This link currently refers to the [general preferences page](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/preferences/current):

> [image: general preferences]

But I think it should refers to [Tag Watching & Ignoring](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/tag-notifications/current) page:

> [image: tag watching]

BTW now I can’t see an option “hide or grey out ignored tags” anywhere on settings pages. Seems it’s only accessible from the main page:

> [image: ignored on main]

Perhaps this should be fixed too.